# changing label text multiple times during one button click Tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

if I link a button to a function that changes a label's text and press the button, the function will be run and when the function is finished, the label will only output the function's last change to the label's text even if multiple changes happen. Is there a way for the label to display the changes to its text as they happen?

Comment: Please post a [mre] then perhaps we can show you how to do it properly.

Comment: Try using `.after` scripts. We can't give you a proper answer unless you give us the important parts of your code.